# Как получить текст с конца строки до точки?

Tags: php

Есть:

```
$string = "test.txt";
$pos = strrpos($string, '.');
echo substr($string, 0, $pos);
```

Хочу получить `txt` а получаю `test`
Как обрезать строку с конца до точки, хочу расширение получить.

Comment: echo substr($string, $pos + 1, strlen($string));

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.pathinfo.php

Comment: или preg_match ( http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-match.php )

Comment: Вопрос решен, спасибо.

Comment: или explode по точке

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться **[pathinfo](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.pathinfo.php)**, который возвращает информацию о пути к файлу.

Пример:

```
$path_parts = pathinfo('/www/htdocs/inc/lib.inc.php');

echo $path_parts['dirname'], "\n";
echo $path_parts['basename'], "\n";
echo $path_parts['extension'], "\n"; // расширение файла
echo $path_parts['filename'], "\n";
```

Соответственно вам можно написать так:

```
$path = 'text.txt';
echo pathinfo($path)['extension'];
```

---

Используя **[substr](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.substr.php)** (Возвращает подстроку) и **[strrpos](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strrpos.php)** (Возвращает позицию **последнего** вхождения подстроки в строке):

```
$path = 'text.txt';
echo substr($path, strrpos($path, '.') + 1);
```